# How do I export a part of an SVN repository with dependencies?

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svndumpfilter

I am trying to migrate a part of an SVN repository using `svnadmin dump`.

The provided svndumpfilter tool doesn't manage copy/move/rename dependencies from directories not included in the export.

Is there a tool which can manage these dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a Python script by Simon Tatham called [svndumpfilter2](http://svn.tartarus.org/sgt/svn-tools/svndumpfilter2?view=markup), which tries to cope with simple dependencies (I found some limitations, though).

You can also check an [article](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/svn.html) about his migration to Subversion and the motivation for the script.

Comment: It's an old answer now, but can you remember the limitations you found with `svndumpfiler2`?

Comment: Mainly related to several levels of copying, IIRC, but I managed to tweak the script to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

With dependencies you mean those specified by the property svn:external?

If yes, I think you should pass to svndumpfilter also the paths referrend in the property.
For example, if your project is in `http://host/project` and the svn:external property is set to `http://host/dependencies` you can do something like

```
svndumpfilter include http://host/project http://host/dependencies < total.dump > project.dump
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get rid of this problem. If you copied a directory/file, you have to include both (source and destination) into svndumpfilter.

However, you can do some tricks:

If you dump a repository not from revision 0, but say e.g. from revision 100, you will get a new repository with revision 1-100 vanished. However, your destination repository has all files/folders in revision 1 as your source repository in revision 100. In this way you can get rid of versioned data without losing the HEAD-Revision.

You can try to dump/load your source repository until your first copy into a "flat" repository, then add the remaining dumps onto it. In this way you can skip the troublesome copy-from revision, as your files are already in the fitting (destination) directory.